# what is the right way to construct multiple stores in mobx-state-tree application?

Tags: mobx-state-tree

Recently I'm using mobx-state-tree in my project to manage state. As there are multiple entities such as Factory, Workshop, Machine etc. I created multiple stores in the application and then use an ApplicationStore to combine them together.

the construct is followed with the example in `mobx-state-tree/packages/mst-example-bookshop`.
But I'm not sure it is the best practise because I met some really confusing problems.

So I just wonder if anyone can give me some other examples of how I should manage the construct of multiple stores.I'd like to hear your opinion and thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to use a root store to instantiate the other stores but it is flexible so you can use a number of approaches. You can find more info and examples in the docs here: https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html